# Argument ... is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm playing with AngularJS, but I'm getting an error message: `Argument 'Controller' is not a function, got undefined` Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/eRamD/17/), and HTML code:

```
<h2>Hata's Tree-Like Set</h2>
<div ng-app ng-init="N=3;" ng-controller="Controller">
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" ng-model="N">  
<div class="tree"></div>
</div
```

Then I define the `Controller` function in JavaScript, which is not registering for some reason.

```
function Controller($scope){
$scope.$watch("N", function(){  ... });}
```

Comment: You can find out your problem, by this checklist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly the same error: `argument 'HelloCtrl' is not a function`, got undefined.

Turns out I had a syntax error in my `hello.js` file...  a missing comma in an array definition, inside `HelloCtrl()`.

I added the comma, and then everything started working!

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesn't,  we don't know where the comma is supposed to go. please give an example

Comment: What he is saying is "it could be anywhere, and nothing, not even the browser console, is going to tell you where". You just have to go over your coed with fine toothed comb. It helps if you can remember whet you changed last, or have a backup version which you can compare with. I get this error fairly often and for me it has always been caused by mis-matched brackets. YMMV.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tracked down my latest such error to array problem. I had to comment out a huge block of code written last midnight & uncomment it bit by bit. I had `myData.push(val: i);` instead of `$scope.myData.push({val: i});`` - mssing `$scope` and missing braces. Naturally, this means that my controller is not a function ;-)  There is just on easy way to to solve this error.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error... argument 'RadioController' is not a function...

I had referenced the Controller wrong in the HTML. I had

```
data-ng-controller="RadioController"
```

when it should have been

```
 data-ng-controller="Radio.RadioController"
```

('Radio' is the module the Controller was in)

Answer (score 5):

In the option of your fiddle, you choose to execute your javasctipt `onLoad`. 
With the `onLoad`option your javascript is added on the `window.onLoad`function :

```
    window.onload=function(){
       function Controller($scope){
          ...
       }
    }
```

So angular can not access to your code because it is in a closure.

With the `no wrap`option, your code is directly added in the page and is accessible to angular : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/eRamD/29/).

You can browse the source to see how it works.

Comment: the slider is supposed to control the complexity of the twig, basically the value `N` in a for loop

Comment: Please explain the `no wrap` option you mention. This answer is missing some context that makes it less useful than it could be.

Comment: just to clarify - the `no wrap` option is within jsfiddle, not angular (you can see it in the control bar on the left). Removing this removes the closure which is what causes the OPs issue. For more on closures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 4):

You can define a controller and register it in one step:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch ....
});
```

If you want the code to work correctly after it's been minified, you have to explicitly specify the dependency on $scope:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function(s) { 
  // you can now name the $scope argument whatever you want
  ...
}]);
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a hard time with this as well. The cause of my problem was that I had an old version of Angular that didn't support the new `as` aliasing.

Make sure you have the latest version of Angular that supports `as`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your $controllerProvider correctly?

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController):

> Name of a constructor function registered with the current $controllerProvider or an expression that on the current scope evaluates to a constructor function.
>
> The controller instance can be published into a scope property by specifying ng-controller="as propertyName".
>
> If the current $controllerProvider is configured to use globals (via **$controllerProvider.allowGlobals()**), this may also be the name of a globally accessible constructor function (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I succeeded in solving this error by downgrading to legacy angular JS (1.2.27).

The same syntax (you have used above) for defining controller and angular JS (1.3.2) is the combination which caused this error.

With angular (1.3.2), following syntax worked for me.

```
var app = angular.module('dummyApp', []);

app.controller('helloController', function($scope){
    <write statements here>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to downgrade to older versions.
You can use both the **as** method or the **angular.module** method.

Also the order of loading your files has to be correct.

(**Consider require js if you have a hard time remembering the order of loading your files**)

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-order the script tags. I put the controller higher than another it depends on.

Took me a few hours, hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

I had this error - I'd got the case wrong in the name of my Controller.

It was registered as CallbacksController... took me five minutes of swearing to spot the case difference (hint - capital B in my case!).